# p5.js with webpack non instance mode

Tags: javascript, webpack, p5.js

I am creating a little p5 application and I am also using webpack. I am using instance mode but I need to access some of p5 functions(like map, sin, ect...) in other file without the instance reference. How can I import thouse functions from P5 without creating a new instance?

Comment: Sounds like a possible design problem. Can you share your code so far as a [mcve] and provide a bit more context of why you need to do this? One solution might be to create a wrapper module that imports p5 and creates and manages a singleton instance. Other modules that need to use your p5 instance will import the p5 instance from the single source of truth. Otherwise, maybe just import p5 from any modules that need its utility functions and use the top-level, uninstantiated versions of these p5 functions.

Comment: sin and most of the functions that p5 has are builtins to JavaScript. For example, `sin` is `Math.sin` (plus some extra stuff, like the ability to use degrees or radians instead of just radians). See if you can import individual functions. If not, then create a new instance in `noCanvas` mode (i'm not sure about the performance hit you'll get from this, but it probably won't be enough to even think about it). The main problem is that p5.js was originally written to be imported via cdn, not used in npm projects (and the attempt at making it worked is bodged together) from what i understand